# ReactiveForm : ValuesChanges is not defined?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

my concern is that I get a valueChanges undefined in a reactiveForm. It starts to make a moment that I struggle on this stuff

Here is the form with the formControl "treasuryTime" (I removed other FormControl without interest):

```
// Form controls
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      treasuryTime: [null, [Validators.required, CustomValidators.requiredMatch]],
      pensionFund: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }
```

the valueChanges in question:

```
this.form.controls['treasuryTime'].valueChanges.subscribe((x: IdentifiantLibelleDto) => {
        if (x) {
          console.log("DELAI TRESORERIE ------  " + x.libelle)
          // return undefined.....
        }
      }),
```

I tried the syntax without success;

```
  this.form.get('treasuryTime').valueChanges.subscribe((x: IdentifiantLibelleDto) => {
  this.form.controls.['treasuryTime'].valueChanges.subscribe((x: IdentifiantLibelleDto) => {.....
```

In the html this is a select type element and I get all the items of the list, so no worries at this level.

```
<div class="c-input c-select" [ngClass]="{'error' : this.form.controls.treasuryTime.invalid && this.form.controls.treasuryTime.touched}">
        <select [attr.aria-label]="page + '.treasuryTime' | translate" required formControlName="treasuryTime">
          <option value="" selected>{{ page + '.duration' | translate }}<span class="c-input__mandatory">*</span></option>
          <option *ngFor="let t of treasuryTimes" [value]="t">{{ t.libelle }}</option>
        </select>
        <span class="c-input__error">{{ 'error.required' | translate }}</span>
      </div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: See that you need subscribe **after** you create the form. BTW, is unnecesary the use of "this" in the .html

Comment: thanks for your answer, my form is build in the ngOnInit().

Comment: It will be better to use it like this:

this.form.get('treasuryTime')

did you wrapped your fromcontrol with fromGroup?
 like so:

<form [formGroup]="bioSection" (ngSubmit)="callingFunction()">

  <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
  </label>
<label>
</form>

please elaborate more on the problem

Comment: thanks, yes I use a FormGroup instance between template/typescript (post edited)

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer...

In HTML I couldn’t retrieve the object with the binding
I used [value]="myObject"

Instead, must be done :
[ngValue] = "myObject"

Hope it will help